# Animate opening of link in webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a several links in my HTML. When a link is clicked, I would like the new page to appear using a fade in/cross-dissolve animation. I have read a bit about CSS animations, but not sure if this is achievable. Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (and don't forget to load the styles at the head):

```
html{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}

html.hide{
    opacity: 0; 
}
```

the HTML

```
<html class='hide'>
...
</html>
```

and the with JS:

```
window.onload = function(){document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = '';}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but I am not exactly sure where in the HTML to include which of the text above. Could you please clarify?

Comment: <html class='hide'>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
html{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}
html.hide{
    opacity: 0; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = '';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>